# How can I maintain directory structure properly with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to get all of my styles (css, scss, less) into css and then minified into one file, index.min.css within dist/test/. However, I don't want to hardcode dist/test in - I want the file name to be dynamic (not always test) so the person can name their project file whatever they want to.

My file structure looks like this:

> dev/
>
> > test/
> >
> > > index.html
> > >       index.js
> > >       index.css
> > >       index.scss
> > >       index.less
>
> dist/
>
> > test/
> >
> > > index.html
> > >       index.min.js

Here's the relevant snippet of my code:

```
var config = {
    src: "./dev/**/", //src location
    build: "./dist/" //dist location
};

gulp.task('styles', function() {

    var lessStream = gulp.src(config.src + "*.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(concat('less-files.less'));

    var scssStream = gulp.src(config.src + "*.{sass,scss}")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concat('scss-files.scss'));

    var cssStream = gulp.src(config.src + "*.css")
        .pipe(concat('css-files.css'));

    var mergedStream = merge(lessStream, scssStream, cssStream)
        .pipe(concat('index.css'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build))
        .pipe(browsersync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));

    return mergedStream

});
```

This code **combines and minifies properly**, but the **location is incorrect** - it ends up in dist/ instead of dist/test where I want it to end up.

Answer (score 0):

```
...

var minimist = require('minimist');

var knownOptions = {
  string: 'folder',
  default: { folder: 'test' }
};

var options = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), knownOptions);

var config = {
    src: "./dev/**/",                  // src location
    build: "./dist/" + options.folder  // dist location
};
...
```

And then you can call your task

```
gulp styles --folder courtney
```

---

Example based on [pass arguments from the command line](https://gulpjs.org/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli) from official docs

Comment: I think you can just omit `knowOptions` altogether and go `var options = minimist(process.argv.slice(2))`. But in that case you will **need** to provide the `--folder` parameter while calling your script, otherwise it will just error out. That's why having a default is a good idea - if the user wants to customize the folder name he is more than welcome, otherwise he will end up with the default  `/test`